# How can I use requests with Ironpython?

Tags: python, com, ironpython, python-requests

I'm trying to run a script that was written with python 2.7, using some libraries that I've installed on my Windows machine - among them numpy scipy, scikit, requests and others.

Now I need to use a COM object dll, so I am writing an IronPython script that loads that dll. However when I try to use or import the python 2.7 code, I get import errors:

> ImportError: No module named requests

How can I use that python 2.7 code I wrote with IronPython? I could run the script with the python 2.7 interpreter through a system command, but that would mean a big waste of time.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know IronPython, but it seems that your libraries were installed using a different Python, and the `PYTHOPATH`s of those two don't match. That, or requests was installed in a place that isn't automatically picked up by IronPython. Check your `sys.path` and see if the requests directory is included. Does numpy import properly?

Comment: trying to append to `sys.path` the path to the python 2.7 libs does not work neither... tried `numpy` and `requests`. I get more import errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IronPython is written in C#, so you can't (easily) use C Extensions for cPython on it.
There is a [port of numpy and scipy](https://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=NumPy%20and%20SciPy%20for%20.Net) for the Microsoft .Net environment.

For pure python packages and modules, appending to sys.path allows you to do imports.
Did you `python setup.py install` your own code? Otherwise it won't be in the installations site-packages and you should add your project's directory to sys.path.

There is an additional problem with requests, an issue with supported encodings (https://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/4565) prevents that from working. The issue has been open for ages.

If you can be more specific about your code and setup, other people could chime in with more suggestions.